# REST. Jersey. How to programmatically choose what type to return: JSON or XML?

Tags: java, xml, json, rest, jersey

I have 2 questions:

**1.** Can I create **one** class, annotate it with JAXB annotations(for XML support) and declare in `web.xml`

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

for JSON (Jackson library) support? Or I need to create separately two classes for JSON and XML?

Or may be exist some more elegant way to cause REST service to return both JSON and XML?

**2.** How I can programmatically choose what type to return (JSON or XML)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your client wants to use a part of the URL to configure the response type, you can use a Servlet filter.

An easy way to implement overriding the representation (media type) could use a URL query parameter:

/resources/todo?format=json

The Servlet filter parses the URL query parameters, and if a format=json is present, replaces or adds the accept header "application/json".

Comment: thanks, but can I configure response type unsing `Response` object when return from method?

Comment: Response can specify the content type: return Response.ok. (...) .type("application/json").build();

Comment: If you're picky about URLs like I am..., you could use a file extension: `/resources/todo.json` or `/resources/todo.xml`

Comment: Jersey already supports selection by extension, if you enable it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369396/limit-path-media-type-mappings-in-jersey
with the ServerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS
(I know this question is older, just linking the answer you wanted, because google brought me here first for the answer of how to change types based on extension)

Answer (score 9):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

---

> Can I create one class, annotate it with JAXB annotations(for XML support) and declare in web.xml for JSON (Jackson library) support?

You can always use an `Application` class to specify a `MessageBodyReader`/`MessageBodyWriter` for the JSON binding.  I believe Jackson provides an implementation in its jar.  Below is an example of an `Application` class that specifies MOXy as the JSON provider:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class CustomerApplication  extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        HashSet<Class<?>> set = new HashSet<Class<?>>(2);
        set.add(MOXyJsonProvider.class);
        set.add(CustomerService.class);
        return set;
    }

}
```

> Or I need to create separately two classes for JSON  and XML?

EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) offers native XML binding and is designed to enable you to use the [same object model for both JSON and XML](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/binding-to-json-xml-geocode-example.html).  You can integrate  it into your JAX-RS application using the `MOXyJsonProvider` class:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

---

> How I can programmatically choose what type to return (JSON or XML)?

**Server Side**

You can specify that your service offers both XML and JSON messages using the `@Produces` annotation.

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("{id}")
public Customer read(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    return entityManager.find(Customer.class, id);
}
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/03/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

**Client Side**

You can use the MediaType to indicate the type of message.  Below is an example using Jersey  client APIs.  Note how the URL is the same, just the requested media type is different.

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/CustomerService/rest/customers");

// Get XML response as a Customer
Customer customer = resource.path("1")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .get(Customer.class);
System.out.println(customer.getLastName() + ", "+ customer.getFirstName());

// Get JSON response as a Customer
Customer customer = resource.path("1")
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .get(Customer.class);
System.out.println(customer.getLastName() + ", "+ customer.getFirstName());
```

***For More Information***

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html

Answer (score 4):

No need for seperate classes, what you need is seperate methods:

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Todo getXML() {
    Todo todo = new Todo();
    todo.setSummary("This is my first todo");
    todo.setDescription("This is my first todo");
    return todo;
}
```

Then in the client side, when you request for the service, you indicate in what format you want it:

```
// Get XML
System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("todo").accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML).get(String.class));
// Get XML for application
System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("todo").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class));
// Get JSON for application
System.out.println(service.path("rest").path("todo").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
```

Comment: thanks, so I understand I need to sent `accept` header from client to get what type I need. But how I can return neccesary type from server?

Comment: Once you add the producess annotation, the framework will do it automatically for you based on the client request

Comment: ok ok:) I understand it) But what if I want to return neccesary type depending on some other facts (not on client's `accept` header)? Or in ither words, how to return `xml` if client's `accept` header is JSON?

Comment: I fail to see under what situation is that viable?! In all situation, the client is the one initiating the reequest and the client KNOWS in what format he would like to get the request, what you are suggesting will probably cause the client to hate you :)

Comment: for example I want to let client to choose type of response in URL: `rest/get/cars/xml` or `rest/get/cars/json`. Then depending on `pathParam` return right type of response.

Comment: Thats a different question, I'd suggest opening a new discussion