# Is there a way to change the output type for restful webservices by a parameter in java?

Tags: java, format, jersey, resteasy, restful-architecture

I wanna use the same restful webservice path to produce xml or json, or a xml with xsl header.
Is it possible using any framework(jersey or resteasy) in java?
Eg:

```java
@Path("/person")
public class PersonService {

    @GET
    @Path("/find")
    public Person find(@QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("outputformat") String outputformat) {
            // do some magic to change output format
            return dao.findPerson(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can write a servlet filter that takes the query string and uses it to set the request's accept header accordingly, then jersey should dispatch to whatever method is annotated with @Consumes that matches.

For example, servlet filter intercepts request "?outputFormat=xml" and sets the Accept header to "application/xml". Then, jersey should dispatch to whichever method in your resource is annotated with: `@Consumes("application/xml")`

This question might help: [REST. Jersey. How to programmatically choose what type to return: JSON or XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382158/rest-jersey-how-to-programmatically-choose-what-type-to-return-json-or-xml)

Answer (score 1):

You could also easily customize Jersey ServletContainer and you won't require another param to pass along. You could negotiate representation using .json or .xml in your URL.

```
public class MyServletContainer extends ServletContainer {

  @Override
  protected void configure(ServletConfig servletConfig, ResourceConfig resourceConfig, WebApplication webApplication) {
    super.configure(servletConfig, resourceConfig, webApplication);
    resourceConfig.getMediaTypeMappings().put("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    resourceConfig.getMediaTypeMappings().put("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
  }

}
```

In your web.xml, you could define the custom servlet as shown below.

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.MyServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.sun.jersey.MyWebApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jersey and use the annotation `@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})`.  You would need to add a mapping feature for POJOs in your application as well.  The include in the `web.xml` file would be

```
<filter>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Other configurations would be necessary, but it is all in the documentation http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html