# Multiple @GET for different MIME - how to consume this with plain HttpURLConnection()

Tags: java, web-services, http, rest

I just realized that it is possible to define something like this in my RESTful resource .java file:

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getPlainTextHello() { ... }

@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String getJSONHello() { ... }
```

Isn't that fantastic? But wait the moment....

**PROBLEM**

I am consuming my API with simple client. Something like this code with help of `HttpURLConnection`:

```
URL obj = new URL("http://some.url/res/hello");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
... /* get response ... conn.getInputStream() */
```

How the server 'know' which one method call to serve the client?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should consider using the same method for different types of "produces":

```
@GET 
@Produces({ "application/xml", "text/plain"}) 
public String getHello() { ... }
```

The different types of "produces" could be handled by JAXB (in case the response is an object...).

You can define the client side "accept" mime type by using:

```
String uri = 
    "http://localhost:8080/hello/";
URL url = new URL(uri);
HttpURLConnection connection = 
    (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

This question provides more insights (and other client side frameworks) related with this problem: [REST. Jersey. How to programmatically choose what type to return: JSON or XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382158/rest-jersey-how-to-programmatically-choose-what-type-to-return-json-or-xml)

Comment: Is it some reason to make a common function?

Comment: I would say that this is the same "resource", only its "representation" varies... so probably there is no reason for having multiple methods to handle them. Furthermore, also consider a situation where you also accept different "request" (@Consume) types (e.g.: "xml" and "json"). You would end up having to create 4 different methods to handle all the possible combinations... Also, by using JAXB you simply can "forget" about the representation issues, it will handle them for you based on the mime types the client specifies for request/response messages.

Comment: Thanks. Please add info about the "Accept" property from client side (this was my original question) and I will accept your response.

Comment: @flyer I have added the code for specifying the "Accept" on the client side... I do think that is indeed the best way to do with "HttpURLConnection"... but if you have flexibility to use other client  frameworks you use: jersey, or other nicer frameworks. Cheers!

Comment: Ahhh. At first look I didn't really understood a link you posted. Now I see the references to WebResource/Client are provided by Jersey... I need to try this.

Comment: You should! It is mainly for server-side part, but has very good client support too!

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want a generic function to do all the common work, and then simply pass this work to the response specific functions you outlined.

```
getHello(String responseType)
{
   // do all your work you'd end up doing in both functions
   switch (responseType):
       case ("json") {
                        return getJSONHello(work);    
                     }
       case ("text") {
                        return getPlainTextHello(work);
                     }

}
```

Comment: Is it some reason to make a common function?

Answer (score 0):

I made some more checks on this and what works for me is just settings Accept:

```
...
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", mime);
...
```

where `mime` is `"text/plain"` or `"application/json"`. This way my server calls one of the GET function.

Anyway I am confused why most answers suggest to use a common one function to serve a @GET and check for type inside this function...