# Consume multiple resources in a RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, xml, rest, jax-rs, wildfly-8

In my web server application I have a method, which modifies an xml document and looks similar to that:

```
@POST
@Path("somePath")
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/zip"})
public Response modifyXml() {
    //some processing
}
```

The consumed zip archive contains the xml file which needs to be modified and some other files.
How can I distinguish between consumed xml file and the archive inside the method and which kind of method parameter should I use to represent this consumed resource?

Comment: `@param filetype:String`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl It definitely makes sense to treat the xml as a string which I am already doing in processing the incoming xml file, but how should I be in case it is a zip archive which contains the xml?

Comment: Does your problem solve question asked here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864158/multiple-get-for-different-mime-how-to-consume-this-with-plain-httpurlconnect

Comment: @Hegde Thanks for pointing! I already viewed this question and thought to separate the resources, but I am afraid it really should be done in one method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to just read from an `InputStream`. You could wrap the `InputStream` in a [`ZipInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html). With `ZipInputStream` you can get a [`ZipEntry`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) with [`ZipInputStream.getNextEntry()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html), then you can get the file name with [`ZipEntry.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getName%28%29). Then just check if the name `endsWith(".xml")`.

With this though, you would need to consume `application/octet-stream`. Here's a simple example

```
@Path("/zip")
public class ZipResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response postZipFile(InputStream is) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder builder;
        try (ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(is)) {
            builder = new StringBuilder("==== Data ====\n");
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = zip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                String filename = entry.getName();
                if (filename.endsWith(".xml")) {
                    builder.append("name: ").append(entry.getName()).append("\n");
                    String xml = filePartToString(zip, (int) entry.getSize());
                    builder.append("data: ").append(xml).append("\n");
                }
                zip.closeEntry();
            }
        }
        return Response.ok(builder.toString()).build();
    }

    private String filePartToString(InputStream is, int size) throws Exception {
        String xml;
        byte[] buff = new byte[size];
        is.read(buff, 0, size);
        return new String(buff);
    }
}
```

Here's a test

```
@Test
public void testResteasy() throws Exception {
    WebTarget target = client.target(
            TestPortProvider.generateURL(BASE_URI)).path("zip");
    File file = new File("C:/test/test.zip");
    Response response = target.request().post(
            Entity.entity(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
    System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
    response.close();
}
```

Using these files in a zip

```
test1.xml
---------
<test1>hello world</test1>

test2.xml
---------
<test2>hello squirrel</test2>

test3.json
----------
{
    "test3":"Hello Girls"
}
```

I get the following result

```
==== Data ====
name: test1.xml
data: <test1>hello world</test1>
name: test2.xml
data: <test2>hello squirrel</test2>
```

---

As an aside, if you have control over how the data is sent, you might want to also look into a multipart solution. There you set content types, and you can name each part, where they're easier to access.

You can see Resteasy's support for multipart [here](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/Multipart.html), and [the required dependency](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/Maven_and_RESTEasy.html).

---

## UPDATE

If you *must* use `application/zip`, there is no standard support for this. So you would need to whip up your own `MessageBodyReader`. It could be something as simple as wrapping and return the already provided `InputStream`

```
@Provider
@Consumes("application/zip")
public class ZipMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<ZipInputStream> {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == ZipInputStream.class;
    }

    @Override
    public ZipInputStream readFrom(Class<ZipInputStream> type, 
            Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, 
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, 
            InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        return new ZipInputStream(entityStream);
    }    
}
```

Then in your resource method, you could just have a `ZipInputStream` parameter, instead of `InputStream`.

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/zip")
public Response postZipFile(ZipInputStream zip) throws Exception {
```

On the client side (with the client API), if you were to use `application/zip`, you would of course need to also write a `MessageBodyWriter` for `application/zip`

---

## UPDATE 2

> **From Comment:** I need my method to be able to consume both a simple xml file and a zip archive which contains the xml file, so I annotate the method something like (pseudo code): "consumes(xml, zip)" and declare a method with the parameter InputStream is; In the method body I then need to determine whether this InputStream is of type xml or a zip archive and want to write something similar to: "if(is of type xml) {then treat is as an xml} else {treat is as a zip archive}. Hopefully now the question is more understandable

We can keep your original method signature accepting both `application/xml` and `application/zip`. Also we can check which on is actually being sent by injecting `HttpHeaders` and getting the `Content-Type` from it. Base on that, we will determine how to extract. Here's another example of how we can complete this

```
@Path("/zip")
public class ZipResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes({"application/zip", "application/xml"})
    public Response postZipFile(InputStream is, @Context HttpHeaders headers) throws Exception {
        String contentType = headers.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
        String returnString = null;

        if (null != contentType) switch (contentType) {
            case "application/xml":
                returnString = readXmlFile(is);
                break;
            case "application/zip":
                returnString = readZipFile(is);
                break;
        }

        return Response.ok(returnString).build();
    }

    private String filePartToString(InputStream is, int size) throws Exception {
        String xml;
        byte[] buff = new byte[size];
        is.read(buff, 0, size);
        return new String(buff);
    }

    private String readXmlFile(InputStream is) {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "utf-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ZipResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return writer.toString();
    }

    private String readZipFile(InputStream is) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("==== Data ====\n");
        try (ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(is)) {
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = zip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                String filename = entry.getName();
                if (filename.endsWith(".xml")) {
                    builder.append("name: ").append(entry.getName()).append("\n");
                    String xml = filePartToString(zip, (int) entry.getSize());
                    builder.append("data: ").append(xml).append("\n");
                }
                zip.closeEntry();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

We would need a `MessageBodyReader` to handle the `application/zip` type. The one above works fine, but we just need to it return an `InputStream` instead of `ZipInputStream`

```
@Provider
@Consumes("application/zip")
public class ZipMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<InputStream> {
    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == InputStream.class;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream readFrom(Class<InputStream> type, 
            Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, 
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, 
            InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        return entityStream;
    }  
}
```

Now with the test

```
@Test
public void testResteasy() throws Exception {
    WebTarget target = client.target(
            TestPortProvider.generateURL(BASE_URI)).path("zip");


    File file = new File("C:/test/test.zip");
    Response response = target.request().post(
            Entity.entity(file, "application/zip"));

    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
    System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
    response.close();

    file = new File("C:/test/test1.xml");
    response = target.request().post(
            Entity.entity(file, "application/xml"));

    System.out.println(response.getStatus());
    System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
    response.close();

}
```

we get the following

```
200
==== Data ====
name: test1.xml
data: <test1>hello world</test1>
name: test2.xml
data: <test2>hello squirrel</test2>

200
<test1>hello world</test1>
```

**Note:** With the client, I had to implement a `MessageBodyWriter` to handle the `application/zip` type. The following is a simple implementation just to get the test to work. A real implementation would need some fixing

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/xml")
public class ZipClientMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<File> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == File.class;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(File t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(File t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, 
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, 
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        IOUtils.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(t)), entityStream);
    }  
}

....

client.register(ZipClientMessageBodyWriter.class);
```

You'll also note in some of the example code, I made use of Apache Commons `IOUtils`. Excuse me for that. I was being lazy :-)

---

## UPDATE 3

Actually, we don't need to `MessageBodyReader`. The algorithm to find the reader will actually just default to the `InputStream` reader, as it supports `application/xml`, so it will already return the `InputStream` whether we have a reader for the `application/zip` or not

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but how can I determine whether the incoming InputStream is a zip archive with the xml inside or just xml file?

Comment: You can allow `application/zip` but you need to write a `MessageBodyReader`. I orginally had that as part of the answer then removed it. I will update.

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't read the entire comment. Let me ponder for a moment :-)

Comment: Let me explain my question a bit more precisely before you ponder=)

Comment: I need my method to be able to consume both a simple xml file and a zip archive which contains the xml file, so I annotate the method something like (pseudo code): "consumes(xml, zip)" and declare a method with the parameter InputStream is; In the method body I then need to determine whether this InputStream is of type xml or a zip archive and want to write something similar to: "if(is of type xml) {then treat is as an xml} else {treat is as a zip archive}. Hopefully now the question is more understandable

Comment: Will the content-type be one or the other? For instance if `Content-Type: application/zip`, then you can wrap it in the `ZipInputStream`. If `Content-Type: application/xml`, then move forward with using the `InputStream`. You can inject `@Context HttpHeaders` into the method to get the content type

Comment: In which case, you would still need the `MessageBodyReader` to handle the `application/zip` type. Just change the `ZipInputStream` in the `MessageBodyReader` to `InputStream` and simply return the `entityStream` in the `readFrom` method.

Comment: Have a look at my **UPDATE 2**. I codified my last two comments

Comment: Also **UPDATE 3** (read this before doing anything from the second update :-)

Comment: any ideas of how to serialize the incoming input stream and then deserialize it? I could serialize it but trying to deserialize I get the "java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C3F786D". I need the process of serialization to be able to create the xml of the input stream, to modify it and then pack that xml into a wrapping class.

Comment: Are you getting this for the zip file or the xml? Or both?

Comment: At the moment I am testing the variant with the xml

Comment: So you're saying this this exception is occurring before it even hits your resource method?

Comment: No no, the resource method nests another method call, which does the modifying of the file. In my unit test I call this nested method and then get the exception.

Comment: Ahhh.. What is this "wrapping class"? Is it possible maybe that's the problem? Hard to tell without seeing your client code. The example client I have above, everything works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68206/discussion-between-arthur-eirich-and-peeskillet).