# multiple mime type as @consumes with multipart file upload

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multipartform-data, spring-annotations

am trying to create restapi such that it can accept either Multipart kind of input or plain json. But while making multipart as optional getting exception that server is expecting multipart input.

```
@PUT
    @Path("/symlink")
    @Consumes({MediaType.WILDCARD,MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    @Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response generateDateRefreshSymlinks(@RequestPart(value="file", required=false) MultipartFormDataInput inputFile,
            @QueryParam("jobId") String jobId ) throws IOException
```

exception:     "description": "RESTEASY003200: Could not find message body reader for type: interface org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataInput of content type: */*"

Comment: Does this answer help you --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/27709335/16572295 ?

Comment: not really @jaos